# multiple checkbox sqlalchemy delete

Tags: python, html, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy and HTML forms and need to understand how to delete multiple rows in my dB table that correspond to are checked checkboxes in my HTML form. As it stands only the first checked item  is being deleted from the table. I was hoping this could be done without a for loop on the SQLAlchemy side?

Here is my HTML code:-

```
<ul>
            {% for alert in alerts %}
                  <li>   <input name="alert_id" type="checkbox" value="{{ alert.alert_id }}"/> Ticker:{{ alert.ticker }}    Price:{{ alert.price }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And the flask python SQLAlchemy script:-

```
if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["alert_id"]:
            Alert.query.filter(Alert.alert_id == request.form["alert_id"]).delete() 
            db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
Alert.query.filter(Alert.alert_id == request.form["alert_id"]).delete()
```

should be

```
Alert.query.filter(Alert.alert_id.in_(request.form["alert_id"])).delete()
```

which does a `SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE alert_id IN (<val>, <val2>)`

Also, it's good to stick to `request.form.getlist("alert_id")` instead of `request.form["alert_id"]` so you can always make sure you get a `list` and not a `KeyError` in case `alert_id` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Can you recommend a  website for a good introduction to SQLAlchemy and a good reference website. I'm likely to run into a lot of issues like this.

Comment: Happy to help, @dbm. The official docs is the best source for reference https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html.
Here's a pretty detailed cheatsheet - https://github.com/crazyguitar/pysheeet/blob/master/docs/notes/python-sqlalchemy.rst